# Debugging grep 2.26 with LLDB causes difference output compared to running grep 2.26 in terminal

Tags: xcode, debugging, grep, lldb

I am in the process of debugging a patched version of grep 2.26 for the company I work for. My question is why would I get different output when running grep through LLDB or GDB with the same argument "grep -c root /etc/passwd" compared to just running grep and argument in terminal?

Results from terminal:

3

Results from LLDB/Xcode

root:*:0:0:System Administrator:/var/root:/bin/sh
daemon:*:1:1:System Services:/var/root:/usr/bin/false
_cvmsroot:*:212:212:CVMS Root:/var/empty:/usr/bin/false
Program ended with exit code: 0

I thought that I have not set it up properly but I get the same result when run through GDB/Netbeans.Any Ideas would be greatly appreciated.
Cheers

Comment: Looks like the `-c` argument isn't being passed to `grep`. What method are you using to tell lldb and gdb the arguments they should give to `grep`?

Comment: Through terminal no debug:
$ grep -c root /etc/passwd
3
LLDB on terminal
(lldb) r -c root /etc/passwd
Process 3175 launched: './src/grep' (x86_64)
arguement : -c
root:*:0:0:System Administrator:/var/root:/bin/sh
daemon:*:1:1:System Services:/var/root:/usr/bin/false
_cvmsroot:*:212:212:CVMS Root:/var/empty:/usr/bin/false
LLDB with Xcode frontend:
under edit scheme/Run/Arguments tab:
-c root/etc/passwd
If I grep -c root /etc/passwd it gives an error that root is not file or directory.
Print statement added for the option variable to make sure the argument was recognised.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution.
The problem occurred because the command called in terminal was pointing to /usr/bin/grep instance instead of the directory I thought I was calling.
to evoke the grep from my directory I needed to use ./grep ... now it matches the debugging environment.
Cheers